# Couldn't find executable named below after rosrun

Tags: ros

To learn ROS, I follow [Learning ROS for Robotics Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1783987588), but I got the following error when executing `rosrun chapter2_tutorials example1_a`:

```
Couldn't find executable named 'example1_a' below /home/MYNAME/catkin_ws/src/learningROS/chapter2_tutorials
```

However,

1. this path exists in `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` (I echo this environment variable to confirm);
2. this path does not exist when executing `rosstack profile`

Here is the list of ROS set:

`ROSLIST_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES="/home/MY_NAME/catkin_ws/devel/share/common-list"`

`ROS_DISTRO="jade"`

`ROS_ETC_DIR="/opt/ros/jade/etc/ros"`

`ROS_PACKAGE_PATH="home/MY_NAME/catkin_ws/src:opt/ros/jade/share:/opt/ros/jade/stacks"`

`ROS_ROOT="/opt/ros/jade/share/ros"`

Also, there is no failure when executing `rosmake chapter2_tutorials`:

[image]

But there is no `chapter2_tutorials` under `~/catkin_ws/devel/lib/`.

The CMakeLists I use is from

https://github.com/AaronMR/Learning_ROS_for_Robotics_Programming/blob/master/chapter2_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt.

And I add

rosbuild_add_executable(example1_a example1_a.cpp)

rosbuild_add_executable(example1_b example1_b.cpp)

in the end of this CMakeList file.

Please let me know if any further information needed and thank you for taking time on my question.

Comment: can you check the file `CMakeLists.txt` in your `package chapter2_tutorials` if it contains the line `rosbuild_add_executable(example1_a source_file.cpp)` ? if there's not, then you have not a node called example1_a. you may look at this [link](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbuild/CMakeLists/Examples) for explanation.

Comment: Hello Yassin, Thank you for the response. But I do add rosbuild_add_executable in CMakeLists.txt. One question, what and where should I have after rosmake? Maybe actually the result is not generated through rosmake. Thank you.

Comment: Another new find is when running rosmake, I got  a lot of ROS_NOBUILD, such as catkin, cmake_module, genmsg, cpp_common, rosclean, rosgraph, genlisp, geneus, genpy, etc. Does it mean the built fail? Thank you.

Comment: can you update your question by adding the content of your CMakeLists ? thx

Comment: Hello Yassin, please let me know if any question about the uploaded CMakeList info. Thank you!

Comment: well, at first sight, everything looks ok. weired that it can't find the node ! So, Just a final check, can you confirm that your node is actually being created under `catkin_ws/devel/lib/*package_name*/*node_name* ` ? if yes, then get us a look at the result of the command `$ export | grep ROS`? (maybe it's the environment set !)

Comment: Hello Yassin, Thank you so much for helping!!! Please let me know if any question about the new update.

Comment: I still cannot figure it out but use catkin to build the project instead. I don't think this approach should be considered as an answer, so just add the comment here.

Comment: there's a mistype there `capter2_tutorials` instead of `chapter2_tutorials` ! could it be the cause ?

Comment: Hello @YassinNasri, This is my typo on this post. In the program I types the word correctly. Sorry for confusing.

Answer (score 4):

You can check the CMakeLists.txt.

Add

```
catkin_package()
```

in CMakeLists.txt and compile it again

Answer (score 2):

This might help:
Solution1:

Go to the file location.
Right click on the file --> properties.
Go to permissions tab: Check the Executable checkbox.

Solution 2:
NAvigate to the file location in terminal:

~/$ chmod 777 <file_name>

Reference: https://www.maketecheasier.com/file-permissions-what-does-chmod-777-means/

Answer (score 1):

I am using python2 in ros

my first line in script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env
```

I add python as follow:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

It fix the issue and rosrun can run executable .py file

Answer (score 0):

You can try the command:

```
~$ rosrun chapter2_tutorials chap2_example1_a
```

because in the `CMakelists.txt`, the name of executable file is not "`example1_a`"

```
add_executable(chap2_example1_a src/example1_a.cpp)
add_executable(chap2_example1_b src/example1_b.cpp)
```